# how to i authenticate through rake task (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, pdf-generation, rake-task

i need to create a pdf from a rake task. therefore i generate the pdf from the model itself.
i use wicket_pdf and search a lot in the net, how to create pdf file. 
in the browser pdf works (simple part right ;-)).

my environment:

- ruby 1.9.3
- rails 3.2.6
- wicked_pdf 0.7.9 => actual_version

here is my solution so far:

```
    # app/controllers/bills_controller.rb
    class BillsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!
      respond_to :html, :pdf

      def show
        @bill = Bill.find(params[:id])
        respond_with(@bill) do |format|
          format.html 
          format.pdf { render :pdf => "mypdf", :disposition => "inline" }
        end
      end
    end

    # app/models/bill.rb
    # solution from https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/84
    class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base

      require 'open-uri'
      def save_pdf
        pdf = open("http://localhost:3000/bills/#{id}.pdf")
        File.open(Rails.root.join("pdfs","#{id}.pdf"), 'wb') { |f| f.print(pdf.read) }
      end

    end
```

from console:

```
Bill.first.save_pdf
```

but i get the error:

```
OpenURI::HTTPError: 401 Unauthorized
```

how do i authenticate devise_user via open-uri from a rake task?

Comment: I'm doing it from a background job and I'm having a similar problem.  The wicked_pdf github issues has some discussion about this, but the problem of logging in still remains....(https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/57)